# Explicit Construction for Cohen’s $p$-ring with imperfect residual field

Tags: commutative-algebra

Let $p>0$ be a prime. Recall that a $p$-ring is a complete DVR $A$ with residual filed $k$ of characteristic $p$ such that $p$ is a uniformizer.

It is known (e.g. Ch 29. of Matsumura’s *Commutative Ring Theory*) that for any field $k$ of characteristic $p$ there is a unique (up to isomorphism) $p$-ring with residual field $k$.

The ring of Witt vectors $A=W(k)$ offers an explicit construction for **perfect** $k$, e.g. Serre’s *Local Fields*.

Is there a similar description when $k$ is **imperfect**? If so, what is it? Any reference(s)?

Comment: @Flyingpencil I’ve already mentioned Serre’s book in main text of the question. Its discussion of Witt vectors assumes $k$ is perfect.